# wireless problem with auto connecting and a hack I use

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet-connection

I purchased a new computer at the beginning of 2012.  An Asus U56E and it is very nice.  The only problem I have had with it is connecting to the internet.  No matter what distro I have tried it won't just connect.

I have to apply a hack (see below) to get wireless to work.  I found this hack somewhere on the net and I have a terminal automatically start at login and this is when I apply the hack.  Wireless won't work till then.

I like Ubuntu but mostly I use Linux Mint.

What I want is to just start my computer and once I get to the desktop be online.  I am pretty sure it is a driver issue but is says there is a driver installed (iwlwifi).  Could the driver be the wrong one?  Could the kernel be causing this problem?  I have no problem connecting to the Internet wirelessly with an old linux distro using kernel 2.6.38.

Is there an easier way to get on wirelessly? If you need more info, just ask.  Thank you for your help.

My computer specs..

```
[~]$ inxi -F
System:    Host: LAPTOP Kernel: 3.5.0-17-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Linux Mint 14 Nadia
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: U56E version: 1.0 Bios: American Megatrends version: U56E.211 date: 09/29/2011
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-2450M CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) 
       Clock Speeds: 1: 800.00 MHz 2: 800.00 MHz 3: 1600.00 MHz 4: 2501.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
       X.Org: 1.13.0 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
       GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.0
Audio:     Card: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: 1.0.25
Network:   Card-1: Intel Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 driver: iwlwifi 
       IF: wlan1 state: up mac: 40:25:c2:8a:e8:88
       Card-2: Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet driver: atl1c 
       IF: eth0 state: down mac: 54:04:a6:36:55:d9
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1750.4GB (51.7% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: ST9750423AS size: 750.2GB 
       2: id: /dev/sdb model: Desktop size: 1000.2GB 
Partition: ID: / size: 9.2G used: 4.4G (51%) fs: ext4 ID: /boot size: 985M used: 47M (5%) fs: ext4 
       ID: /home size: 677G used: 31G (5%) fs: ext4 ID: swap-1 size: 1.07GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap 
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0C mobo: N/A 
       Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 
Info:      Processes: 162 Uptime: 1:23 Memory: 699.6/5874.8MB Client: Shell inxi: 1.8.4
```

---

```
[~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 (rev 67)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

---

```
[~]$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:04:a6:36:55:d9  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:3880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:386545 (386.5 KB)  TX bytes:386545 (386.5 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:25:c2:8a:e8:88  
      inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4225:c2ff:fe8a:e888/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:339216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:129505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:478921988 (478.9 MB)  TX bytes:14815164 (14.8 MB)
```

---

```
[~]$ iwconfig
wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"FBI Van #2"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: E0:46:9A:58:C9:08   
      Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:52921  Invalid misc:5378   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

---

The hack that I use.. (I have to manually enter this text in a terminal, enter my password before my computer will connect to the internet via wireless.)  I don't just type it in, I made an alias (wifi) and then password.  As soon as I hit enter, my computer is online.

```
[~]$ sudo modprobe -r iwlagn && sudo modprobe iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
```

Comment: Is your hack for iwlagn? The driver is actually iwlwifi.

Comment: Yes, the hack appears to be for iwlagn and yes, the driver is wilwifi and indicated with the command 'inxi -F.'  Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to automate the process so you needn't do anything on boot, please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

A new, empty file will open. Add a single line:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit.You should be all set.

Comment: The wilwifi.conf file was not empty, but I did comment out some code and entered your code and now it works 'properly.'  Thanks for your help.